# 2011 RAM 1500 Trouble Starting

Tags: battery, starting, ram, no-crank-no-start

I have a 2011 RAM 1500 Laramie 5.7. Within the last 6 weeks I replaced the battery. After I did that my truck would fail to start on the first few turns of the key. When I turn the key I hear the "click" like it's got a dead battery. Sometimes it would happen 1 time and then turn over, other times it would try to start it up to 8 times before starting. Sometimes I have to turn the key real slow for it to start.
It is intermittent. I have driven it and then stopped for 5 minutes just to have it give me trouble starting. I’ve also left it for 4 days with no issue. Once it starts it runs fine.
I’ve had the starter and alternator tested; they’re good. I’ve also had the battery replaced.
My thoughts are that there is either
A. A parasitic draw (unlikely since I only have one thing plugged in, and it would have manifested sooner)
B. A bad ignition switch.

Thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You state the truck fails to start. Do you mean, when you turn the key, nothing happens? Or when you turn the key the engine cranks over but the engine never fires up?

Comment: When I turn the key it clicks like it's trying to start, but it doesn't have enough juice from the battery. It's always started eventually. I normally turn the key to the on position and let it sit for a bit. As stated above, a very slow key turn sometimes does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems as though you haven't secured the battery terminals well enough to the battery posts. This could be due to an oxidation layer on the terminals or battery which needs to be cleaned off, or because they haven't been tightened enough. It could also be an issue with your battery cables, but probably less likely. Go through and disconnect your the terminals, cleaning both the cable end and the battery (a metal bristled brush works best for this), then firmly reattach. Check to ensure there no corrosion at the starter and grounding ends of the cables. Check the cables themselves for any type of bulges along the length. This would indicate corrosion inside of the cables, which could also inhibit starting.